# DotNetOpenAuth request extended permission

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I am quite new to DOTNetOpenAuth and I want to request extended permissions for facebook using the FacebookClient. I am using V 4.3.4.13329

I have the following code

```
  var scope = new List<string>
              {
                  "email",
                  "status_update",
                  "share_item",
                  "publish_actions",
                  "user_friends",
                  "user_likes",
                  "user_status",
                  "friends_status"
              };

 var c = new FacebookClient(appId, appSecret, scope.ToArray());

 result =  c.VerifyAuthentication(ControllerContext.HttpContext, new Uri(uriString: Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new{returnUrl = returnUrl}, "http")));
```

However the server always returns the fowllowing error

[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request) +283
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address) +100
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.FacebookClient.QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, String authorizationCode) +235
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client.VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnPageUrl) +142

Is there something i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance